# wp-cron.php - timeout

Tags: wp-cron

I found via Query Monitor plugin, that there is some HTTP request error during page load. I looked at the error table, and here I found that problem is with this:
[image]
[FULL_IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDKAR.png)

How can I delete this wp-cron job, or whatever is that?

Comment: wp-cron is what publishes future dated posts and other time related scheduling things, simply getting rid of it entirely will break things

Comment: no I don't want to disabel wordpress "cron". I just want to remove this record in wp-cron jobs. But don't know which code, or plugin call this job. Anyway thanks to WP Super Cache, future post are not working.,

Comment: every page load calls that URL using a nonblocking call

Comment: There isn't enough detail to say which cron job "this" is. If specific job is at fault (and rest of them are functioning normally) you will need to figure out which one it is. Dumping cron schedules and noting which coincide with faulty request would be a start.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My solution was to define the timeout constant for the cron job by adding this line in `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT', 60);
```

I added this before the line `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` and it worked. By default this is set to 0.01 seconds, which to me it makes no sense. This line sets it to 60 seconds.